# Get 405 method not allow when post to login processing url (Spring Security)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I tried to use Postman to test login processing url set in Spring Security config:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/list")
            .access("hasRole('USER') or hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('DBA')")
            .antMatchers("/newuser/**", "/delete-user-*")
            .access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
            .antMatchers("/edit-user-*")
            .access("hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('DBA')")
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login-processing")
            .usernameParameter("ssoId")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .and()
            .rememberMe()
            .rememberMeParameter("remember-me")
            .tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository)
            .tokenValiditySeconds(86400)
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");
}
```

When I access default `/login`, I got this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login Page</title>
    </head>
    <body onload='document.f.ssoId.focus();'>
        <h3>Login with Username and Password</h3>
        <form name='f' action='/login-processing' method='POST'>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>User:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='text' name='ssoId' value=''>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='password' name='password'/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type='checkbox' name='remember-me'/>
                    </td>
                    <td>Remember me on this computer.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan='2'>
                        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <input name="_csrf" type="hidden" value="26d11d4c-1477-41e7-9639-abe2f4ca114e" />
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And then I use Postman to test `/login-processing` endpoint I got this:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1498962411086,
    "status": 405,
    "error": "Method Not Allowed",
    "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException",
    "message": "Request method 'POST' not supported",
    "path": "/login-processing"
}
```

Why `/login-processing` can be access from `/login` but cannot accessed by Postman?

Answer (score 0):

Please to add the contextPath to the form action : `${contextPath}/login-processing` , you can use the JSTL `<c:url value='/login-processing' />`